# Change WooCommerce product loop add to cart button to a "view more" linked to the product

Tags: php, html, wordpress, woocommerce, product

I have both external and physical products on WooCommerce and instead of the "Adding to cart" button which sends you to either an external product or adds the product to the cart, I'd like to have for both internal and external products a button that says "view more" and send users to the detailed page.

I was able to use the following answer code from my previous question:

```php
add_filter( 'woocommerce_loop_add_to_cart_link', 'replace_external_product_loop_add_to_cart_link', 100, 3 );
function replace_external_product_loop_add_to_cart_link( $button, $product, $args ) {
    // Only for external products
    if ( $product->is_type('external') ) {
        $button = sprintf( '<a href="%s" class="%s" %s>%s</a>',
            esc_url( $product->get_permalink() ),
            esc_attr( 'button' ),
            isset( $args['attributes'] ) ? wc_implode_html_attributes( $args['attributes'] ) : '',
            esc_html__( 'Ver Detalles' )
        );
    }
    return $button;
}
```

But my physical products still say add to cart...

See example [www.faceup-romanorte.com](https://www.faceup-romanorte.com), I haven't been able to figure out how to add this to "normal products".

Comment: Some feedback on the answer below will be appreciated, please.

Answer (score 1):

To have this working for all products (external and other product types), you will have to simply remove `if ( $product->is_type('external') ) {` like:

```php
add_filter( 'woocommerce_loop_add_to_cart_link', 'replace_external_product_loop_add_to_cart_link', 100, 3 );
function replace_external_product_loop_add_to_cart_link( $button, $product, $args ) {
    return sprintf( '<a href="%s" class="%s" %s>%s</a>',
        esc_url( $product->get_permalink() ),
        esc_attr( 'button' ),
        isset( $args['attributes'] ) ? wc_implode_html_attributes( $args['attributes'] ) : '',
        esc_html__( 'Ver Detalles' )
    );
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of your child theme (or in a plugin). Tested and works.

Note: This code replaces your previous code.